# Determining how the OpenMP atomic directive is implemented

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp, atomic

A compiler that implements the OpenMP standard may, but is not obliged to, exploit special hardware instructions to make certain memory updates following a `#pragma omp atomic` directive atomic, avoiding expensive locks. According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/OpenMP.html, GCC implements an atomic update as follows:

> Whenever possible, an atomic update built-in is used. If that fails, a compare-and-swap loop is attempted. If that also fails, a regular critical section around the expression is used.

1. How can I determine which of the three is actually used on a given machine and GCC version? Is there some verbosity option for GCC that I can set to find out without having to profile my program or look a the generated bytecode?
2. Is there some documentation listing CPUs/architectures that provide atomic addition/increment/etc instructions, allowing me to predict the outcome for a given machine?

I'm using GCC versions 4.2 to 4.6 on a variety of different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look at the intermediate tree representations with the `-fdump-tree-all` option. Given that option, GCC writes a set of files at several intermediate steps and one can observe the successive transformations applied to the tree. The `.ompexp` file is of particular interest here, since it contains the tree just after the OpenMP expressions were expanded into their concrete implementations.

For example, the block inside the `parallel` region in the following simple code:

```
int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
       #pragma omp atomic
       i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

is transformed by GCC 4.7.2 on 64-bit Linux into:

```
;; Function main._omp_fn.0 (main._omp_fn.0, funcdef_no=1, decl_uid=1712, cgraph_uid=1)

main._omp_fn.0 (struct .omp_data_s.0 * .omp_data_i)
{
  int D.1726;
  int D.1725;
  int i [value-expr: *.omp_data_i->i];
  int * D.1723;
  int * D.1722;

<bb 2>:
  D.1722_2 = .omp_data_i_1(D)->i;
  D.1723_3 = &*D.1722_2;
  __atomic_fetch_add_4 (D.1723_3, 1, 0);
  return;

}
```

which finally ends into:

```
00000000004006af <main._omp_fn.0>:
  4006af:       55                      push   %rbp
  4006b0:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4006b3:       48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  4006b7:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  4006bb:       48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  4006be:       f0 83 00 01             lock addl $0x1,(%rax)
  4006c2:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4006c3:       c3                      retq
```

As for the second question, it might also depend on how GCC was built.

Comment: Accepted for answering the first question, which was my primary objective.

Answer (score 0):

GCC will define macros

```
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_1 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_2 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_4 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_8 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_16 1
```

if the respective operations are available.

In general, one can always expect to have compare and swap (either in the form of a CAS or LL/SC) on any architecture, which supports multiple processors.

In addition, on x86 there's atomic increment and decrement.